# Button not able to find event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPrintCA"  onclick="btnPrintCA_Click" runat="server" 
 ImageUrl="~/Content/Image/print_32.gif" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void btnPrintCA_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
      {
          ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "_Page", 
                  "showPVDialog('ContentAssignmentPrint.aspx','')", true);
      }
    catch 
      {

      }
  }
```

Error:

> does not contain a definition for 'Button' and no extension method
>   'btnPrintCA_Click' accepting a first argument

Comment: open designer page and check whether the event is registered or not?

Comment: This code works, it must be an underlaying/different problem. Maybe you are using the Button class statically, search your code behind for "Button".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write  O' and 'C' in UpperCase in 'onclick' and try it. otherwise check your designer file in which button click event is registered or not.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnPrintCA"  OnClick="btnPrintCA_Click" runat="server" 
 ImageUrl="~/Content/Image/print_32.gif" />
```